# Garbage collector problem in C#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

In C# code, I have three objects **A**, **B** and **C**. **A** and **B** each hold a reference to **C**. When **A** is destroyed I would like the reference from **B** to **C** to be deleted as well so that **C** can be destroyed by the Garbage Collector.

Is there a way to do this without deleting it manually from **B**? (The destructor in **C** is not called before the reference from **B** to **C** is deleted, so it is not effective here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Is B referenced from anywhere else in you application?

If B is only accessable through A, then B and C will be "removed" when A is "removed".

**Solution 2**

You should send a signal to B when A is "removed". If B is known to A you can signal B from A. I would use an [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) pattern for this

**Solution 3**

Instead of directly referencing C from B, you can use a WeakReference from B to get to C.

Answer (score 10):

It smells like a job for a [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx):

> A weak reference allows the garbage
>   collector to collect an object while
>   still allowing an application to
>   access the object. If you need the
>   object, you can still obtain a strong
>   reference to it and prevent it from
>   being collected.

Sounds like you should refer from B to C via a WeakReference, instead of directly.

Answer (score 7):

First off, define "remove". And then consider using WeakReference class.